# pre-selecting value from dropdown (Combo box) in extjs?

Tags: extjs, combobox, drop-down-menu, extjs4

I have a combo box which displays item quantity. Based on item quantity selection i am displaying price value of the item. By default i am setting price value to first item value. However when i load the page, i want my combo box to display first item qty i.e 100.

[image]

Problem: it should load Qty : 100 rather loading blank

So i have a store defined as

```
Store =  new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'Store',
        root: 'storevalue',
        autoLoad: false,
        baseParams: { itemid: '${itemID!""}',
                      adjustPrice: '${adjustPrice}',
                      overrideShowPrice: '${overrideShowPrice}' },
        url: 'ListQtyPrice.epm',
        fields: [ 'qty', 'rawprice', 'displayPrice' ]
    });
```

Combo box to display Qty

```
 <#if Select>
         new DBEComboBox({
            name: 'orderqty',
            displayField: 'qty',
            valueField: 'qty',
            id: 'order-qty',
            store: Store,
            forceSelection: true,
            mode: 'remote',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            allowBlank: true, 
            listWidth: 202,
            triggerClass: 'orderqty-trigger', 
            width: 200
            ,defaultValue: 100
            ,listeners: {
                // for price adjustments
            }
         });
        </#if>


Store.load({
            callback: function() {
            alert("reached");
            Ext.getCmp('order-qty').setValue(Store.getAt(0).get('qty'));
            var oqc = Ext.getCmp('order-qty');
            var value = Ext.getCmp('order-qty').getValue();
            alert(" hey :" +value); 
            }
        });
```

Able to see hey: 100 in alert statements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into this problem a couple times. The only way I've actually gotten this resolved was to call `setValue` on the combobox after the store has loaded, you could just add a listener on the store, but that always seemed somewhat messy to me. I usually have a stand-alone event listener like this:

```
Store.on('load',function(store) {
    Ext.getCmp('order-qty').setValue(store.getAt('0').get('qty'));
});
```

**EDIT:** 18 Jan 2012

OK as mentioned here is a complete working example of ComboBox with a default value being set. This is done using ExtJS 4.02, should work fine with 4.07 though, not sure about 4.1.

Make sure you put your correct extjs path in the links (see brackets at the top of html), otherwise just put both combo-example and data.json at the same directory level and they should run fine:

data.json:

```
[
  {"value":1,"name":"Option 1"},
  {"value":2,"name":"Option 2"},
  {"value":3,"name":"Option 3"}
]
```

combo-example.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">    
        <title>Combo Box Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[your extjs path]/resources/css/ext-all.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="[your extjs path]/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    Ext.onReady(function() {

        // the datastore
        var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['value', 'name'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'data.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });

        // a window to hold the combobox inside of a form 
        myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            title: 'A Simple Window',
            width: 300,
            constrain: true,
            modal: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                // the form to hold the combobox
                xtype: 'form',
                border: false,
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelWidth: 75
                },
                bodyPadding: '15 10 10 10',
                items: [{
                    // the combobox
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    id: 'myCombo',
                    fieldLabel: 'A Label',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    store: myStore,
                    //queryMode: 'local',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%'
                },{
                    // shows the selected value when pressed
                    xtype: 'button',
                    margin: '10 0 0 100',
                    text: 'OK',
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('Name: ' + Ext.getCmp('myCombo').getRawValue() + 
                              '\nValue: ' + Ext.getCmp('myCombo').value);
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
        // show the window
        myWindow.show();

        // function to give the combobox a default value
        myStore.on('load',function(store) {
            Ext.getCmp('myCombo').setValue(store.getAt('0').get('value'));
        });

    });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was going to post a solution along the same lines (+1). Mad-D, you have to make sure Geronimo's snippet is BEFORE any load call to the store. If it still didn't work, any errors in firebug? Can you verify that the store, once loaded, does indeed have records?

Comment: This always works fine for me... Is this for ExtJS**4**? Your store and combobox are still configured the same as above? Did you put the example above outside of all other functions but inside of Ext.onReady? If you want to be dirt simple about it (but not dynamic at all) you could always just add a `value` config to the combobox e.g.: `value: '100'` or `value: 100`

Comment: i tried these things 1. 'store.getAt('0').get('qty'))' in alert and got value as expected i.e 100 but it didn't set defaultvalue.  2. when i tried value:'100' and value:100 it's not showing default set as 100.

Comment: might have something to do with the trigger

Comment: @amol : no errors in firebug, `setValue` function is passing default value but it's just not displaying :(                                              @Geronimo: i did try making hideTrigger: false, Any other clue ? spent 3 days just to figure out why

Comment: Can you try posting more of your code, so I can see how it is connecting up?

Comment: @ Mad-D You are calling `Ext.getCmp('order-qty_cbo')` but the combo id is still `id: 'order-qty'`. EDIT: unless that part just wasn't updated?

Comment: @Geronimo: does `Ext.getCmp('order-qty_cbo')` should match `id: 'order-qty'` ?

Comment: @Mad-D yes any places that say `Ext.getCmp('order-qty_cbo')` should say `Ext.getCmp('order-qty')` it needs to match the id: field of the combobox. - that should handle your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6830/discussion-between-geronimo-and-mad-d)

Comment: @Mad-D ok added complete working example, be sure to put in your own extjs path (brackets at the top of combo-example.html). Put these two files (combo-example.html and data.json)at the same directory level and they will run fine.